# Rename several columns using start with in r

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I want to rename multiple columns that starts with the same string.
However, all the codes I tried did not change the columns.

For example this:

```r
df %>% rename_at(vars(matches('^oldname,\\d+$')), ~ str_replace(., 'oldname', 'newname'))
```

And also this:

```r
df %>% rename_at(vars(starts_with(oldname)), funs(sub(oldname, newname, .))
```

Are you familiar with a suitable code for rename?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, if your question has been solved, please select one of the answers you prefer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take `iris` for example, you can use `rename_with()` to replace those column names started with `"Petal"` with a new string.

```r
head(iris) %>%
  rename_with(~ sub("^Petal", "New", .x), starts_with("Petal"))

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width New.Length New.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5        1.4       0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0        1.4       0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2        1.3       0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1        1.5       0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6        1.4       0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9        1.7       0.4  setosa
```

---

You can also use `rename_at()` in this case, although `rename_if()`, `rename_at()`, and `rename_all()` have been superseded by `rename_with()`.

```r
head(iris) %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("Petal")), ~ sub("^Petal", "New", .x))
```